# Brunch watch error - ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: node.js, npm, brunch

After reinstalling my system I have tried to setup my frontend project and came  up with the annoying error with `brunch watch` which does not disappear anyhow.
[image]

```
node version is 6.1.0
npm version is 3.8.3
brunch version is 1.8.0
OS: Windows 10
```

The weird thing is that with the same configuration it does not working only for me and for my colleague but working for the rest.

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your brunch version. Brunch < v2.x uses npm v2.x.